# Processing.js and File Empty or File Not Found issue on Github pages

Tags: javascript, processing.js, github-pages

After setting up a Github page, when trying to load a Processing.js .pde file, I have been getting the following errors:

```
# <file.pde> is in https://raw.github.com/
# <canvas data-processing-sources="https://raw.github.com/.../file.pde"></canvas>

# On Firefox:
NetworkError: 404 Not Found - <file.pde>
uncaught exception: Processing.js: Unable to load pjs sketch files: <file.pde> ==> File is empty.

# On Chrome:
OPTIONS <file.pde> 404 (Not Found)
XMLHttpRequest cannot load <file.pde>. Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
Uncaught Processing.js: Unable to load pjs sketch files: <file.pde> ==> File is empty.
```

Both of them seem to say `<file.pde>` does not exist but when I try to access it from the browser, I am able to retrieve it. Also, if I copy and paste the contents of the file directly into a `<script>` tag in index.html then everything works properly.

Does anybody have a clue on what might be causing this?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the GitHub page in question?